# Receiving unexpected syntax error in absolute value calculator

Tags: python, cmath

Code:

```
print ("Welcome to my Calculator")
print ("Calculators: Absolute Value [av]")

load = int(input("Enter the calculator code here: "))

if load == av:

 import cmath

 import math

 avnum2 = int(input("Enter the number to have it's absolute value found: ")

 **avsol** = cmath.fabs (avnum2)

 print ("The solution (absolute value) is: ", avsol)
```

There is a syntax error on avsol, and yes, I imported cmath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
avnum2 = int(input("Enter the number to have it's absolute value found: ")
                                                                          ^
```

You're missing a closing `)` on this line.